# MS Access: outer join in a search form

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database with a search form.

I have an "Object" table with amongst other things, a "name" field, and an "owner" table with a "name" field as well.

Between the two, I have a join table so I have a many-to-many relationship

An object does not necessarily have an owner.

In my search form, I have two unbound fields: "object name" and "owner name".

**What I want to do:**

- When the user leaves both fields blank, he gets a list of all the objects (including those with no owner), and if that object has an owner it is also displayed in the list.
- When the user fills something in the "object name" field, he gets a list of all the objects containing the entered substring (including those with no owner).
- When the user fills something in the "owner name" field, he gets a list of all the objects where the owner name contains the entered substring (ignoring NULL owners).

**What I did thus far:**

I made a query with a left outer join, and a criteria on Object.name using the value of the "object name" textfield

That works fine for use case 1 and 2, but there's no owner filtering in case 3

However if I add a criteria on Owner.name based on the "owner name" textfield, case 3 works fine, but case 1 and 2 don't work anymore (making the left outer join obsolete)

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you do a FULL OUTER JOIN instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: By default access doesn't offer this possibility, but I just found this article: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm

I'll try and see

Comment: I'm not sure a full outer join would be the solution though. I don't want to list the owners that are not attached to any object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you could use a Continuous Forms form with the following Record Source...

```
SELECT Objects.ObjectName, ObjectOwners.OwnerName
FROM (ObjectOwnership INNER JOIN ObjectOwners ON ObjectOwnership.OwnerID = ObjectOwners.OwnerID) INNER JOIN Objects ON Objects.ObjectID = ObjectOwnership.ObjectID
UNION ALL
SELECT Objects.ObjectName, NULL AS OwnerName
FROM ObjectOwnership RIGHT JOIN Objects ON Objects.ObjectID = ObjectOwnership.ObjectID
WHERE ObjectOwnership.ObjectID IS NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

...and then put a couple of text boxes and a "Filter" command button in the form header to update the forms `.Filter` property to filter the records as desired, like this:

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
Dim sFilter As String
If IsNull(Me.txtObjectFilter.Value) And IsNull(Me.txtOwnerFilter.Value) Then
    Me.FilterOn = False
Else
    If IsNull(Me.txtObjectFilter.Value) Then
        sFilter = ""
    Else
        sFilter = "ObjectName LIKE ""*" & Me.txtObjectFilter.Value & "*"""
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtOwnerFilter.Value) Then
        If Len(sFilter) > 0 Then
            sFilter = sFilter & " AND "
        End If
        sFilter = sFilter & "Ownername LIKE ""*" & Me.txtOwnerFilter.Value & "*"""
    End If
    Me.Filter = sFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub
```

When the form opens it shows all records...

[image: FirstOpened.png]

...and then we can filter by object...

[image: ObjectFilter.png]

...or by owner...

[image: OwnerFilter.png]

...or both, for that matter.

### Edit

A similar technique for Subforms would be to save the query above as `[ObjectOwner_base_query]` and specify that as the `Record Source` of the Subform, then change the VBA code very slightly, to

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
Dim sFilter As String, sSQL As String
sFilter = ""

If Not IsNull(Me.txtObjectFilter.Value) Then
    sFilter = "ObjectName LIKE ""*" & Me.txtObjectFilter.Value & "*"""
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtOwnerFilter.Value) Then
    If Len(sFilter) > 0 Then
        sFilter = sFilter & " AND "
    End If
    sFilter = sFilter & "Ownername LIKE ""*" & Me.txtOwnerFilter.Value & "*"""
End If

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM ObjectOwner_base_query"
If Len(sFilter) > 0 Then
    sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE " & sFilter
End If
Me.RecordSource = sSQL
End Sub
```

(It appears that modifying the `.Filter` property of a subform can cause Access to act strangely; updating the `.RecordSource` property seems to produce better results.)

Comment: Oooooh ok, dynamically filtering the form sounds like a plan indeed. I didn't think of it this way. I'll test this right away, thank you.

Comment: Actually this isn't working for me, because I display the data in a subform, and you can't modify the filter property of a subform. I'll have to find an anternative way to do this.

Comment: I got it working by simple referencing the parent's components.

However Access crashes in the following scenario:
1) Open form and click filter (displays correctly all the entries)
2) Enter a value for owner and filter (does exactly what I want)
3) Reset Object and Owner to Null and filter (access crashes and has to restart)

Looks like setting the filter on, then off doesn't work well :(

Comment: @user1747281 I have used filters on subforms before, but the associated controls have always been controls in the Form_Header of the subform itself, not controls in the parent form. Also, what version of Access are you using?

Comment: @user1747281 I checked one of my previous projects and now realize that my previous comment is misleading. I included a mechanism for filtering subform records but I did not use the subform's `.Filter` property. Instead, I stored a "base query" for the unfiltered records, used that as a basis for the filtered records by tweaking the WHERE clause, and then made it the `.RecordSource` for the subform. Perhaps I tried using the subform's `.Filter` and failed (although I think I'd have put that in my code's comments).

Comment: So... modifying the recordsource was indeed a much better solution and also easier to implement :-)

Perhaps you could put that solution as a new answer so I can accept that one and give you the credit for it